# Call relationship with js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a relationship between comment's and user's model. I call comment with ajax. It's only part because I'm using library which use ajax:

```
$.each(response, function (index, item) {
   console.log(item);
});
```

It's works correctly but this not:

```
$.each(response, function (index, item) {
   console.log(item.user);

});
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: No way to know without you showing us what `item` looks like. Provide a sample of `response` data as per [mcve]

Comment: This way is not relationship ,this is just iterator data

Answer (score 0):

From the minimal code I would assume you're not fetching the users via the magic method item->users() before returning the response.

To access it like that in a view which only has reference to the response and not the controller.  The response would then need to have that information.